# How to limit data to only the last 5 results

Tags: mysql

I have the query below to fetch the number of row and group them by week. It works great.

```
SELECT  
    WEEKOFYEAR(searched_on) AS weekno,
    COUNT(*) AS num_search, 
    SUBDATE(searched_on, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(searched_on) DAY), INTERVAL + 0 DAY AS date_of_week,              
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY WEEK(DATE_SUB(searched_on, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ORDER BY weekno ASC
```

How can I modify this in order to select only the last 5 results without using `ORDER BY weekno DESC LIMIT 5` in order not to alter the way data has been arranged. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you like to use `ORDER BY weekno DESC LIMIT 5`? This is the right way to go at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add the `ORDER BY weekno DESC LIMIT 5` and push the query into a subquery, then have the outer query reorder ascending:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT  
    WEEKOFYEAR(searched_on) AS weekno,
    COUNT(*) AS num_search, 
    SUBDATE(searched_on, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(searched_on) DAY), INTERVAL + 0 DAY AS date_of_week,              
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY WEEK(DATE_SUB(searched_on, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
    ORDER BY weekno DESC LIMIT 5
) inner
ORDER BY weekno
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `limit` used in mysql.

add the `limit 5` after the code `ORDER BY weekno ASC`. means add it at the end of query.

Here is [the tutorial](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm).

#### Example

Use the below query:

```
SELECT  
    WEEKOFYEAR(searched_on) AS weekno,
    COUNT(*) AS num_search, 
    SUBDATE(searched_on, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(searched_on) DAY), INTERVAL + 0 DAY AS date_of_week,              
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY WEEK(DATE_SUB(searched_on, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) ORDER BY weekno ASC 
    LIMIT 5 OFFSET (num_search-5) //add this line
```

Comment: That would retrieve the first five, not the last five results as requested by @Lomse.

Comment: @jm_toball I have updated the answer. I think now it will be according to OP.\